# C++ compiler differences ( VS2008 and g++)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I tried compiling the following code in Linux and VS 2008:

```
#include <iostream> //  this line has a ".h" string attached to the iostream string in the linux version of the code
using namespace std; // this line is commented in the linux version of the code
void main()
{

  int a=100;
  char arr[a];

  arr[0]='a';
  cout<<"array is:"<<arr[0];

}
```

This line works in the g++ version but does not work in the Visual Studio.
It throws the following error:

```
1>c:\users\bibin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\add\add\hello.cpp(7) : error C2057: expected constant expression
1>c:\users\bibin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\add\add\hello.cpp(7) : error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
1>c:\users\bibin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\add\add\hello.cpp(7) : error C2133: 'arr' : unknown size
```

Is this a valid statement ?? How can two compilers have different interpretation of the same langauge

Comment: What is your setting for the compiler to use in Visual Studio? The default is Microsoft Visual C++. GCC, however, compiles ISO C++. They aren't the same - there are some things that are legal in Microsoft's implementation of C++ that aren't legal in ISO C++ and vice versa.

Comment: @thomas: So is there a way to change it to ISO C++ setting ? I would like to the code written for one to work in the other machine . The ones which dont involve system calls atleast.

Comment: g++ does not use ISO C++ by default, it uses ISO with GNU extensions. If you want standard C++, use the -pedantic flag (and then the VLA will fail on gcc, since it is non-standard). To get standard C++ in Visual Studio, avoid any project types with "CLR" in the name, and use the /Za option to disable extensions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a C99 feature:

```
char arr[a]; // VLA: Variable Length Arrays (C99) but not C++!
```

GCC supports many features from C99, but VC doesn't and I think it won't in the near future because they are concentrating on C++ more and more. Anyway, you could just change the declaration to:

```
  const int a=100; // OK the size is const now!
  char arr[a];
```

Comment: You mean they're concentrating on C#?

Comment: No, C++. The compiler is usually known as Visual C++. It happens that C++ was forked from c89, so it's easy for C++ compilers to offer a C89 mode for legacy C code. But supporting C99 is a lot more work.

Comment: Also, C99 features like VLAs are not part of Standard C++, or even of C++0x, so MS are right not to support tem, IMHO.

Comment: Note that MSVC's `_alloca` is comparable to glibc's `alloca`, so you can get a valid multi-platform replacement with a little bit of macro-magic.  Not sure what's available on other major OSes/architectures.

Comment: FWIW, the suggested workaround (const int a) does *not* work any more with VS2013. :(

Comment: Apparently not with VS2012 either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827599/oaidl-h319-error-c2057-expected-constant-expression

Answer (score 9):

All compilers implement the C++ standard in subtly different ways. However, the problems you are getting with g++ are because by default it enables lots of language extensions. To get warnings about these, you should  *always* compile with at least the -Wall and -pedantic flags:

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic myfile.cpp
```

which will give the following errors/warnings:

```
myfile.cpp:1:119: error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
myfile.cpp:2: error: '::main' must return 'int'
myfile.cpp: In function 'int main()':
myfile.cpp:6: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'arr'
myfile.cpp:9: error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Even without the -Wall or -pedantic, I get a warning that the X.h header is deprecated, with the <X> I get the cout not defined errors, as you would expect, as the <X.h> version uses the global namespace not std.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing `int a` to `const int a`. The C++ standard states that the size of arrays should be a constant expression. The definition of a constant expression is (5.19.1):

> In several places, C + + requires
>   expressions that evaluate to an
>   integral or enumeration constant: as
>   array bounds (8.3.4, 5.3.4), as case
>   expressions (6.4.2), as bit-field
>   lengths (9.6), as enumerator
>   initializers (7.2), as static member
>   initializers (9.4.2), and as integral
>   or enumeration non-type template
>   arguments (14.3). constant-expression:
>   conditional-expression An integral
>   constant-expression can involve only
>   literals (2.13), enumerators, const
>   variables or static data members of
>   integral or enumeration types
>   initialized with constant expressions
>   (8.5), non-type template parameters of
>   integral or enumeration types, and
>   sizeof expressions. Floating literals
>   (2.13.3) can appear only if they are
>   cast to integral or enumeration types.
>   Only type conversions to integral or
>   enumeration types can be used. In
>   particular, except in sizeof
>   expressions, functions, class objects,
>   pointers, or references shall not be
>   used, and assignment, increment,
>   decrement, function-call, or comma
>   operators shall not be used.

`int a = 100` is not a constant expression according to this definition.

Answer (score 1):

in microsoft c++, it's not valid to create array whose size can't be determined at compile time on stack.
You either have to create the array on heap or use a constant to specify the array size.

```
char *arr = new char[size];
const int size2 = 100;
char arr2[size2];
```

Comment: I don't think this has to do with Microsoft. In standard C++, this is not correct. See @Neil answer for more detail why GCC allows that.